# Python 3.6: Reading a non-empty binary file is interpreted by Python to be empty

Tags: python, binary, byte, aes

I have the following code, where 'password' is a string which is passed into the function. The issue is such that when I attempt to read the file created in the first half of the code, Python interprets it as being empty (despite the fact that File Explorer and text editors tell me it contains content). The 4 print statements are to assist with debugging (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470886/python-thinks-a-file-is-empty-when-opened-in-binary-read/)).

```
def encryptcredentials(username, password):
    # Create key randomly and save to file
    key = get_random_bytes(16)
    keyfile = open("key.bin", "wb").write(key)

    password = password.encode('utf-8')

    path = "encrypted.bin"

    # The following code generates a new AES128 key and encrypts a piece of data into a file
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(password)

    file_out = open(path, "wb")
    [file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext)]

    print("the path is {!r}".format(path))
    print("path exists: ", os.path.exists(path))
    print("it is a file: ", os.path.isfile(path))
    print("file size is: ", os.path.getsize(path))

    # At the other end, the receiver can securely load the piece of data back, if they know the key.
    file_in = open(path, "rb")
    nonce, tag, ciphertext = [file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1)]
```

The console output is as such:

```
the path is 'encrypted.bin'
path exists: True
it is a file: True
file size is: 0
```

[Here's an image of how the file is displayed in File Explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEVXa.png)

It appears that there's content in the .bin file produced at `[file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext)]`, but I can't get Python to read it.

Welcoming all suggestions. I'm running Python 3.6, 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `close` or even `flush` the file after `file_out.write(x)`, so your data are writing from `buffer` to the file.

```
[file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext)]
file_out.close()
```